# Grails 3 and GORM 6 for MongoDB - duplicated key error

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails3

Environment:

- Grails 3.2.9
- GORM 6.1.2 for MongoDB 3.4.2

This is my (simplified) domain class

```
class Cluster {

    String name
    String slug

    static constraints = {
        name        blank: false, unique: true
        slug        blank: false, unique: true, validator: { return it == it.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/[^\w-]/, '') }
    }

    static mapping = {
        collection 'Cluster'
        id name: 'slug'
    }

}
```

As you can see I mapped the `slug` property to be the document `_id`.

I can successfully add a document with

```
Cluster cluster = new Cluster(name: 'Dallas', slug: 'dal05')
cluster.insert(failOnError: true)
```

and everything works fine. But if I execute the same `insert` command again I get a duplicated key exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server localhost:27017. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error index: db.Cluster.$_id_ dup key: { : "dal05" }', details={ }}]
```

while I would have expected a simple validation error, stating duplicated key.

However, although the `unique` constraint fails, validation is correctly triggered for the other two (empty value or e.g. 'Dal05' -capital letters not allowed-).

Without mapping the id on `slug` property, so leaving the default `assigned` logic, everything works as expected.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is actually a bug, scheduled to be fixed in upcoming GORM release 6.1.5.

Ref. issue: https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/951